# php for loop to remove common words

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a text file that maintains a list of words.

What I am trying to do is pass a string(sentence) to this function and remove the word from the string if it exists in the text file.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$str1= "the engine has two ways to run: batch or conversational. In batch, expert system has all the necessary data to process from the beginning";

common_words($str1);

function common_words($string) { 
$file = fopen("common.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$common = array();
while(!feof($file)) {
  array_push($common,fgets($file));
  }
fclose($file);

$words = explode(" ",$string);
print_r($words);

for($i=0; $i <= count($words); $i+=1) {
    for($j=0; $j <= count($common); $j+=1) {
            if($words[$i] == $common[$j]){
            unset($words[$i]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

It doesn't seem to work however. The common words from the string are not being removed. instead I am getting the same string with the one I started.

I think I am doing the loop wrong. What is the correct approach and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: no this is a tiny part of my project...

Comment: Try to print $common array, I think You insert whole file content in to one array value.

Comment: Why are you using `$i <= count($words)` when starting from 0?

Comment: I thing function must have return statement :)

Comment: @Liutas it does not have to, see my answer.

Comment: I have used var_dump($words) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the line

```
        if($words[$i] == $common[$j]){
```

change it to

```
        if(in_array($words[$i],$common)){
```

and remove the second for loop.

Comment: Ummmm what is the difference between those two?

Comment: It submitted before I finished typing

Comment: this would remove the need for the second loop then.

Comment: I just figured that out 3 minutes ago. Fixed

Comment: its not taking in $common...However `if(in_array($words[$i],array("the","an"))){
` works...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
foreach($common as $cword){
    str_replace($cwrod, '', $string); //replace word with empty string
}
```

Or in full:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$str1= "the engine has two ways to run: batch or conversational. In batch, expert system has all the necessary data to process from the beginning";

common_words($str1);

function common_words(&$string) { //changes the actual string passed with &

    $file = fopen("common.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

    $common = array();
    while(!feof($file)) {
        array_push($common,fgets($file));
    }
    fclose($file);

    foreach($common as $cword){
        str_replace($cword, '', $string); //replace word with empty string
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe just for coding style use file_get_contents() instead of fopen() too ;)

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo lol true too, but I did not want to get into it :-P

Comment: Can this work also `$arr = array_merge(array_diff($words, $common));` ?

Comment: Watch out for "an" in common words, and (for example) "sandcastle" in the sentence string... consider using preg_replace with the \b word boundary marker... remember that you can also pass a search array to str_replace (and preg_replace) so no need to do each common word in a loop

Comment: Its giving me the same string...your answer and that one too

Comment: @asdgfas sagas - note the & in the function declaration - function common_words(__&__$string) so it simply changes the passed argument rathe rthan your needing to assign a result from the call to the common_words() function